# Asp.net MVC: controller with first parameter as json and second parameter as string from View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

We have a situation where we would like controller to get First parameter as json (model) as second parameter as some additional data other than model (such as Flag, source control from where event is driven etc.), we have tried tweaking with jQuery but all ended up error shown in the browser inspect element.

We have our controller typically like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(Bar b, string additionaldata)
{
    if (additionaldata="Deleted")
    {

    }
    else if (additionaldata="Favorite")
    {

    }
}
```

And inside view its something like this:

```
$("#delete").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Index/Foo",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#myform").serialize(), 
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done(function (model) {
                        $("#Foo_Id").val(model.Foo.Id);
                    });
                });
```

As far as model is concerned, this jQuery is working fine, but as far as we try to add some additional parameter, we are clueless.

Please suggest how we may pass it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On option is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) to build the model and add additional data

```
var formdata = new FormData($('#myform').get(0)); // serialize the form
formdata.append('additionaldata', 'Favorite'); // add additional properties
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Foo")',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,         
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, just curious to know how it became second parameter where we have added the option in json. We thought it would add some string in model itself.

Comment: Not quite sure what your asking. The `append()` method just adds a name/value pair to the data being posted - in this case `additionaldata='Favorite'`. Because you have a matching parameter (`string additionaldata`) it will be bound. You could also just do it manually with you original code but `data: $("#myform").serialize() + '&additionaldata=Favorite`,` but it could get a bit messy.

Comment: This is what exactly I have asked, by this you meant it is controller actions' capability that it extracts parameter from json string intelligently?

Comment: Perhaps your think that `.serialize()` results in json? - it doesn't - it does exactly what a form submit button does - encodes the form controls as a string - use `console.log($("#myform").serialize());` to see the output - its will be just `property1=someValue&property2=anotherValue&....`